# Unable to install audio drivers on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, sound-card

I am not able to install audio drivers on Windows 7.
While installing VIA HD Audio Codec Driver I get following message:

[image: We can't find HD audio device]

`Dxdiag` results:

[image: System info]

[image: Sound Info]

[image: Sys Manage]

Comment: What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the audio device? Where did you get that driver package from?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a compatible HD audio device?

Comment: @and31415 motherboad: G41-M Combo Gigabytes so i found Driver from company's site: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3505#dl ...VIA audio driver....and start to install it

Comment: @jet how can i check whether i have HD audio device ??

Comment: OK, it's HD audio (as shown in your link). Are you running installation "as Administrator"?

Comment: yes i tried with right click "run as administrator" but i got same error message.

Comment: Have you checked that "Azalia Codec" is enabled in the BIOS (section 2.7 of the [User manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-g41m-combo_e.pdf))? It's possible that the HD Audio entries in the device list you show is some other device which does HD audio.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, just now I checked that BIOS option it is set to AUTO

Comment: in first image notification icon on right side showing red icon what it means...or in last imge there is nothing like yellow...mark in Computer management